# How to check how my process' CPUs are affined?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, tuned

When I log into my host, I find that my processes are affined to a subset of cores:

```
# taskset -cp $$
pid 2040's current affinity list: 0-15,17,19,24-39,41,43
```

I don't know why. This occurs for root or any other login shell. I have scoured /etc/, looking for strings 'affin' or 'taskset' in the files:

```
find /etc -type f -exec grep -i taskset {} \; -print
find /etc -type f -exec grep -i affin {} \; -print
```

...nothing. I have performed

```
# pwd
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
# cat cpuset.cpus
0-47
```

...the whole boat is in there. I can't for the life of me figure out where that affinity list is being set.

I should mention perhaps that I *did* have the cpu-partitioning tuning on this machine previously, but I changed it to 'throughput-performance' and removed the `cpu-partitioning-variables.conf` file from `/etc/tuned`, and I think there may be an artifact left over from that procedure, but I can't find it.

BTW, we have:

```
# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1160.36.2.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/vg00-root ro nofb splash=quiet crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=vg00/root nosoftlockup mce=ignore_ce ipv6.disable=1 transparent_hugepage=never spectre_v2=off nopti LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Thanks.

Comment: Again `auditd` seems like the best option for the task: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-use-auditd-to-monitor-a-specific-syscall/

Comment: Not a bad idea to look at system calls, but rather than set up auditd I simply strace'd the main sshd daemon and didn't see anything. But actually, I wouldn't expect to since the cpu's are set to 0-15,17,19,24-39,41,43 on the main sshd. Thus children will simply inherit the same cpu affinity. Anyway, there are no other system calls that will show up in auditd over and above the strace output, so I don't think this is informative. pid 1 has the same cpu set. So the question remains: where did pid  1 get its affinity list from?

Comment: You make it sound like your affinity is set from the `initrd` - then look into it :-)

Comment: Thanks. So I discovered that the cpu-partitioning tuning sets up the initrd with some fanciness, and it set 'CPUAffinity=0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 17 19 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 41 43' in the initrd's etc/systemd/system.conf. Dammit. So when you switch out of cpu-partitioning, it's not completely cleaned up!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @artem-s-tashnikov, I think the answer can be found in the initrd. See https://github.com/redhat-performance/tuned/issues/381, where I say:

> I set my system with the cpu-partitioning tuning, and a CPU affinity list of 0-15,17,19,24-39,41,43. Tuned has some components in the tuned.conf that include "bootloader", so the initrd is changed. Specifically, in the initrd the /etc/systemd/system.conf contains "CPUAffinity=0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 17 19 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 41 43"

> We decided that we did not want to use this tuning, and changed it to throughput-performance. After reboot, I discovered that systemd has a CPU affinity list of 0-15,17,19,24-39,41,43.

> So changing INTO the cpu-partitioning modifies the initrd, but changing OUT of it does not put it back. It leaves this artifact lying around, which requires one to discover it on one's own. It may be good to mention it in the docs, at least. Thanks.

Comment: I saved the old initramfs.img file for safety, then performed a dracut -f -v and rebooted. Problem solved!